# How to parse unorderd lists where <ul> is sibling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-parsing, cheerio

I'm parsing an html file with cheerio.

The part that I'm stuck on is rendered as follows:

```
Fruit
- Banana
  - Ripe
  - Rotten
- Apple
Car
```

but the underlying html is unexpected

```html
<td>
  Fruit
  <ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Ripe</li>
      <li>Rotten</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
  </ul>
  Car
</td>
```

Visually `Banana` is a child of `Fruit` and `Ripe`+`Rotten` are children of `Banana`. However in the underlying html they are siblings. This is where my problems begin.

My instinct is to parse it recursively however I can't figure out how to attach the "siblings" as children of the previous node

A test for the above example would expect the following output:

```json
[
  {
    "text": "Fruit",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Banana",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "Ripe"
          },
          {
            "text": "Rotten"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Car"
  }
]
```

My current attempts look like some variations of the following:

```js
interface Note {
  text: string,
  children?: Note[]
}

function parseNote(note: cheerio.Cheerio): Note[] {
  const notes: Note[] = []
  let note: Note

  note.contents().each(function parseNoteGroups(): Note {
    const element = $(this)[0]
    // reached end of note group
    if (element.type === 'text') {
      if (note.text) {
        notes.push(note)
      }
      note = {text: $(this).text(), children: []}
    }

    if ($(this).is('li')) {
      if (children.length > 0) {
        return { text: $(this).text(), children }
      }
      return { text: $(this).text() }
    }

    if ($(this).is('ul')) {
      $(this).children().each(function () {
        children.push(parseNoteGroups.bind(this)())
      })
    }
  })

  notes.push(note) // push last note

  return notes
}
```

It has a few problems with it. But I'm struggling to make this work conceptually. Thanks for reading and I look forward to any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: The issue is because your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `ul` as a child of another `ul`. It needs to be `<ul><li>Banana<ul><li>Other options....</li></ul></li></ul>` and so on

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I thought so too. But the original html files come from a large and frequently used data set. I cannot alter the html. My browser renders it without complaints as seen above.

Comment: It renders correctly as most browsers will correct the HTML for you, however the issues arise when you attempt to parse the structure using JS - as you've now discovered. There may well be a hacky solution to band-aid the output, however the best solution by far is to fix the HTML output so the JS can be written correctly. At the moment if the browsers amend how they deal with malformed HTML, your system will break.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see. So Chrome fixes the HTML but doesn't show the fixes in the inspector?